# This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'boolean' and '1' have no overlap

Tags: angular

I am getting this following error in angular application. I tried !viewState.successState === 1 but the same error prevails

```
[ngClass]="{ 'form-border-success': viewState.successState == 3, 'form-border-error': !viewState.successState == 1 }
```

Error

```
This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'boolean' and '1' have no overlap.
```

Comment: Whats the initial value of `viewState.successState`

Comment: Are your sure your `successState`is a number? The error indicates it is a boolean

Comment: You should place the condition `viewState.successState == 1` in parantheses with the exclamation mark right outside of the parantheses in other to invert the result of the condition.

Comment: Why not just `viewState.successState !== 1`?

Answer (score 3):

Do `viewState.successState != 1` instead of `!viewState.successState == 1`